# How to match a range of characters with regex to replace them?

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to hide some info of a string. This string is a card number so I want to save only the first 4 and last 4 digits and the rest is going to be 'X'

For example if I have this card `12345678901234` I want it to be `1234XXXXXX1234`

What regular expresion could I use to match those characters?

```
const hide = card => card.replace(/First4AndLast4/g, 'X')
```

Comment: Why a regex if you already know the positions? `const hide = card => card.slice(0, 4) + 'XXXXXX' + card.slice(card.length - 4)`

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/gP4od8/1 Use this regex: `/(\d{4})\d{8}(\d{4})/` with the replacement string `$1XXXXXXXX$2`

Comment: `const hide = card => card.slice(0, 4) + "X".repeat(card.length-8) + card.slice(-4)`

Answer (score 0):

```js
const hide = card => card.slice(0, 4) + "X".repeat(card.length-8) + card.slice(-4)
console.log(hide('111111111111'))
```

Comment: Upvote for `"X".repeat(card.length-8)`. I've searched for something like that but wasn't successful.